# Angular 11 Forms and Http POST

Tags: html, angular, forms, post

I'm trying to post information I entered from my text boxes but I'm receiving an error,

```
core.js:6210 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
```

I was wondering as to why my variables are appearing as undefined? Additionally, how might I fix this problem?

**Component File**

```
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-WeatherData',
  templateUrl: './AddWeatherData.component.html',
})


export class PostDataComponent {
  baseUrl: string;
  date: number;
  temperatureC: number;
  summary: string;
  weatherForm: FormGroup;
  

  constructor(public http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.baseUrl = "https://localhost:44347/WeatherForecast";
    this.weatherForm = formBuilder.group({
      Date: new FormControl(),
      TemperatureC: new FormControl(),
      Summary: new FormControl()
    });
  }

  CreateData() {
    const params = new HttpParams({
      fromObject: {
        'date': this.weatherForm.value.date.toString(),
        'temperatureC': this.weatherForm.value.temperatureC.toString(),
        'summary': this.weatherForm.value.summary.toString()
      }
    });
    let endPoints = '';
    console.log(params);
    this.http.post(this.baseUrl + endPoints, {},{ params: params }).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
}
```

My HTML file includes the forms setup and the type declarations are text for each of the variables I included. Is this an issue?

**HTML File**

```
<form [formGroup]="weatherForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputDate">Date</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDate" formControlName="Date">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputTemp">Temperature C</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputTemp" formControlName="TemperatureC">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputSummary">Summary</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSummary" formControlName="Summary">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="CreateData()">Add New Weather Data</button>
</form>
```

Comment: `Date`, `Summary`, `TemperatureC` are not the same as `date`, `summary` and `temperatureC`. Casings matter.

Comment: Best to use consistent camel casing for all object properties. Also you might consider posting the whole form object as is with ```this.http.post(this.baseUrl + endPoints, this.weatherForm)```. That's the typical pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

debug at

```
fromObject: {
        'date': this.weatherForm.value.date.toString(),
        'temperatureC': this.weatherForm.value.temperatureC.toString(),
        'summary': this.weatherForm.value.summary.toString()
      }
```

and check the value of `this.weatherForm.value`

all properties are case sensitive **TemperatureC** is not equal to **temperatureC**

and if you execute `undefine.toString()` then you will get the error

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your code with below,

```
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-WeatherData',
  templateUrl: './AddWeatherData.component.html',
})


export class PostDataComponent {
  baseUrl: string;
  date: number;
  temperatureC: number;
  summary: string;
  weatherForm: FormGroup;
  

  constructor(public http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.baseUrl = "https://localhost:44347/WeatherForecast";
    this.weatherForm = formBuilder.group({
      Date: new FormControl(),
      TemperatureC: new FormControl(),
      Summary: new FormControl()
    });
  }

  CreateData() {
    const params = new HttpParams({
      fromObject: {
        'date': this.weatherForm.value.Date.toString(),
        'temperatureC': this.weatherForm.value.TemperatureC.toString(),
        'summary': this.weatherForm.value.Summary.toString()
      }
    });
    let endPoints = '';
    console.log(params);
    this.http.post(this.baseUrl + endPoints, {},{ params: params }).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
}
```